Sending Nil value to Rails API in Query String from JS
I'm querying a Searchkick endpoint where I want to find all results where a field is nil.
The query in the console
Product.search('*', where: { category_id: nil })
correctly returns results.
When passed from the client nil, null and all others are interpreted as strings so my query becomes
Product.search('*', where: { category_id: 'nil' })
Is there a rails way or a specific encoding to use for query strings to allow it to be correctly parsed as nil without diving into the params hash and searching for strings?

@engineersmnky the title implies that it's send as a query string and not JSON encoded.

To handle this scenario, you need to manipulate the query parameters on the server side to convert the string 'nil' (or 'null') back into a proper nil value before passing it to the Searchkick query. Here are a few approaches:
def search
  category_id = params[:category_id]
  category_id = nil if category_id.blank? || category_id == '_nil'
  
  products = Product.search('*', where: { category_id: category_id })
  render json: products
end


This works, just trying to avoid it as not only do I need to check category_id but any other nil value which involves traversing all the params. Thank you

The FormData format doesn't actually have a (working) concept of nothing as it's not typed and the values are just strings.
It's kind of implied that with formdata the client should not serialize incomplete inputs (like unchecked checkboxes).
The closest you get is an empty string which can be sent by just omitting the RVAL.
irb(main):001:0> Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query("foo=&bar=2&baz=3")
=> {"foo"=>"", "bar"=>"2", "baz"=>"3"}

While it's trivial to convert the empty strings into nils:
irb(main):007:0> params = ActionController::Parameters.new(Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query("foo=&bar=2&baz=3"))
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"foo"=>"", "bar"=>"2", "baz"=>"3"} permitted: false>
irb(main):008:0> params.transform_values { |v| v.empty? ? nil : v }
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"foo"=>nil, "bar"=>"2", "baz"=>"3"} permitted: false>

YMMV as there are a lot of potential bugs that can occur if you equate "not filled in" with explicitly nothing.
A better idea is to invent a token for nothing (Rails doesn't have one) or send a POST request with a JSON payload instead of using the query string. Or you can embrace the Form Object pattern instead of just forwarding whatever the internet happens to throw at your controller into the model.
class SearchForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
 
  attribute :foo

  def foo=(val)
    super(val.empty? ? nil : v)
  end
end


The challenge you’re facing arises because when data is passed from the client (e.g., via query parameters in an HTTP request), nil and null are converted to strings like "nil" or "null" instead of being interpreted as Ruby's nil. Here's how you can properly handle this scenario in your Rails application:
Solution 1: Parameter Conversion in Controller
One way to solve this issue is by converting "nil" or "null" values back to nil in the Rails controller. You could define a helper method to process the parameters.
Example
# app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    category_id = convert_to_nil(params[:category_id])
    @products = Product.search('*', where: { category_id: category_id })
    render json: @products
  end

  private

  def convert_to_nil(value)
    value.in?(['nil', 'null', '']) ? nil : value
  end
end

Solution 2: Use a Custom JavaScript Value
You can avoid sending "nil" or "null" from the frontend by sending an explicit placeholder value (e.g., "__nil__") to signal the need for nil in the backend.
JavaScript Code
const query = { category_id: selectedCategory || "__nil__" };
fetch(`/products?${new URLSearchParams(query)}`);

Controller Adjustment
def index
  category_id = params[:category_id] == '__nil__' ? nil : params[:category_id]
  @products = Product.search('*', where: { category_id: category_id })
  render json: @products
end

Solution 3: Use presence or blank? Check
If the presence or absence of the parameter is enough to decide the query logic, you could use Rails’ presence method:
category_id = params[:category_id].presence
@products = Product.search('*', where: { category_id: category_id })

Solution 4: Encode nil Using Query Parameter Standards (Optional)
If you are using JSON in the body of requests instead of query parameters, you can directly pass null in the JSON payload.
fetch('/products', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({ category_id: null }),
});

Controller Example
def index
  category_id = params[:category_id]
  @products = Product.search('*', where: { category_id: category_id })
  render json: @products
end

These solutions help ensure that nil is correctly interpreted without requiring excessive manipulation of the params hash in every request.
